# How i can custom Time Picker Dialog minute progressing by 15 minute

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android application for car booking and I want to make a custom TimePicker Dialog progressing every quarter of an hour every 15 minute.

My code:

```
package com.boosterbc.can;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button b1; 
    final Calendar time= Calendar.getInstance();
    private int pHour = time.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    private int pMinute= time.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bttime);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TimePickerDialog().show();      
            }
        });
    } 
    public Dialog TimePickerDialog()
    {
        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener t= new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) { 
                pHour=hourOfDay;
                pMinute=minute; 
            }
        };
        imePickerDialog dialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,t,pHour, pMinute,true);
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of one `TimePickerDialog`, use a `DialogFragment` with two `NumberPicker`s on its layout: first one for hours with values from 0 to 23, second one for minutes, with values from 0 to 3 and custom displayed values:

```
numberPickerMinutes.setMinValue(0);
numberPickerMinutes.setMaxValue(3);
numberPickerMinutes.setDisplayedValues(new String[]{"00", "15", "30", "45"});
```

After users picks a value from minutes picker, convert it to minutes:

```
pMinute = numberPickerMinutes.getValue() * 15;
```

Comment: friend how i can develop two numberPiker dialog instead timepickerdialog ?

Comment: @user3461457 just create new layout with two number pickers and inflate `DialogFragment` with it. About using dialog fragments, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html